# How to use request module inside NodeJs routes

Tags: node.js, express, module, request, httprequest

How to correctly use the request module inside the app.get('/axe'). I find only request module usage in other questions but how to trigger that function

```
var request = require("request")

var url = "https://www.lonelyplanet.com/usa/san-francisco/attractions/de-young-museum/a/poi-sig/1340028/1329646";

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/axe', (req, res, next) => {
req.request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
})
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as :

```
  app.get('/axe', (req, res, next) => {
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {    
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
      }
    })
 });
```